# Divergence free part of laplacian operator in cylindrical coord. (Curl Curl operator)

Tags: coordinate-systems, laplacian

I want to derive $\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{V}$ in cylindrical coordinates. My variables are $(u,v,w)$ in $(z,r, \theta)$ (axissymetric, radial and azimuthal directions).
I computed first stage of this operator:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times (\nabla \times V) = \nabla \times 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_r w - \frac{1}{r} (\partial_{\theta} v -w) \\
\frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} u - \partial_z w \\
\partial_z v - \partial_r u
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Additional terms are due to covariant derivative in cylindrical coordinates:
\begin{equation}
A_{j,k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{kk}}} \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_k} - \Gamma^i_{jk} A_i
\end{equation}
Which will translate to:
$\partial_{\theta} w = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} w + \frac{v}{r}$ and
$\partial_{\theta} v = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} v - \frac{w}{r}$

Up to now I believe everything is OK. (Strong believe)
But how we deal with covarant derivates when we compute second derivative?:
$\partial_{\theta}(\partial_z w) = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{z\theta} w + \frac{1}{r} \partial_z v$

Here I took the derivative in z before derivative in r. But for radial direction it is not so obvious:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\theta}(\partial_r w) = \partial_r(\partial_{\theta} w) = \partial_r (\frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} w + \frac{v}{r}) =
-\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_{\theta} w + \frac{1}{r} \partial_{r\theta} w - \frac{v}{r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \partial_r v \end{equation}
compared to
\begin{equation} \partial_{\theta}(\partial_r w) = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{r\theta} w + \frac{1}{r} \partial_r v \end{equation}

Which approach is correct ?